# What does this notation mean in regards to the inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, inner-products

$$\langle \cdot , \cdot\rangle : \mathbb R^n\; \times \;\mathbb R^n \Rightarrow \mathbb R$$

Are the dots within the $\langle$ and $\rangle$ a pair of $n$ dimensional vectors that are mapping the dot product of the set $\mathbb R^n$ with itself which maps that set to the real numbers?

What it looks like to me is the vectors are mapping onto the Cartesian product of two $n$ dimensional spaces which are then mapped onto the real numbers.

Comment: It indicates that it is a function of two variables; replace each dot with one argument. It takes a pair of vectors (each one from $\mathbb{R}^n$) and maps them to a scalar.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A function is an ordered triple.  Let's consider the function commonly written as $f(x) = 2 x + 1$.  This function is actually three different sets: ( Domain, Range, Mapping ).  For $f$, the function would be $f = \left( [-\infty,\infty], [-\infty,\infty], \{2x + 1 : x \in \mathbb{R}\}\right) = \left(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R},\{2x+1:x\in\mathbb{R}\} \right).$

A way to say that something is a function is just to describe what the domain and range is $f:\text{Domain}\rightarrow\text{Range}$.  In our case, $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  We sometimes write $f(\cdot)$ instead of $f$.  If we were to do so, we would write $f(\cdot):\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  And if we want to specify the mapping, we would do so afterwards. For our example we would say $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=2x+1$.

So what about your notation?  The inner product is a function.  It accepts two different vectors as input.  With it's special notation of brackets, we denote this as $\langle\cdot,\cdot,\rangle$.  What is its domain?  The domain is the Cartesian cross product of the underlying field (which, in your case, looks like the real numbers): $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.  And its range is the set of scalars.

So that leaves the notation: $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This needs some editing (second paragraph ends mid-word, for example)

Comment: Thank you soo much

Comment: The notation $f : X \to Y$ does *not* specify the domain and range of a function.  It specifies the domain and codomain of the function.  The range (or image) of a function is a subset of the codomain.  For example, the function $$f :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} : x \mapsto x^2$$ has codomain $\mathbb{R}$, but its range is $f(\mathbb{R}) = [0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Xander Henderson There are multiple definitions of range:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(mathematics)

Comment: A function is **not** an ordered triple. Exactly the same way $3$ is **not** $\{\{\{0\}\}\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the dots are a pair of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Inner products are a generalization of the familiar dot product of two vectors.

Comment: Perfect thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The "usual" notation for a function is to specify its "name", its domain and codomain, and (perhaps) a formula which assigns an element of the codomain to each element of the domain.  For example
$$ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto x^2 $$
defines a function "named" $f$, which takes elements of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by squaring them.

This notation works well when the function is named by a variable, and we can use the usual prefix notation (e.g. the value that the sine function takes at a point $x$ is typically written by prefixing the name of the function to a value in the domain:  $\sin x$).  However, there are many functions in mathematics which don't use this kind of prefix notation:  norms and absolute values are written with vertical bars which enclose the variable (e.g. $\|x\|_2$ might denote the $L^2$-norm of $x$), inner products are often written with angle braces (e.g. $\langle u, v \rangle$ denotes the inner product of $u$ and $v$), and so on.

For these kinds of infixed functions, it is nice to have a notation which makes it clear how the function behaves.  The usual trick is to leave dots as placeholders.  Thus
$$ \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} $$
defines function which is "named" $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ and which takes elements of $\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ via the (implicit) assignment $(x,y) \mapsto \langle x, y\rangle$.  The dots just tell the reader where to plug in the variables (where, in this case, each of the variables is an $n$-dimensional vector with entries in $\mathbb{R}$).

This notation also comes up in places where a function may have multiple arguments, but only one of them is really important.  For example, I work with functions of the kind
$$ \zeta_E(\cdot, \delta) : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} : s \mapsto \int_{0}^{\delta} t^{s-1} |E| \,\mathrm{d}t. $$
Because $\delta$ is typically fixed early on (and therefore plays the role of a parameter), there is no good reason to specify where it comes from or what it does in the notation.  However, it is still a variable on which the value of the function depends, so it is part of the notation.  On the other hand, the complex variable $s$ is the thing that we are *actually* interested in varying, so its position is marked with a dot.  The functions "name" is $\zeta_E(\cdot, \delta)$, whereas the value of the function at $s$ is denoted by $\zeta_E(s,\delta)$.

Comment: @NicNic8  Regarding your edit:  I prefer the notation $L^2$-norm; this is consistent with many of the books on my shelf (Folland's *Real Analysis* and Evans *Partial Differential Equations* were the first two books I checked---both use this notation), and is consistent with the [MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html) on these spaces.  Thus I have reverted your edit.